# office 365 mail authentication is successfully but after authentication i got some error in console spring boot how to fix this error

Tags: java, outlook, office365

554 5.2.0 STOREDRV.Submission.Exception:SendAsDeniedException.MapiExceptionSendAsDenied; Failed to process message due to a permanent exception with message Cannot submit message. 0.35250:0A006981, 1.36674:0A000000, 1.61250:00000000, 1.45378:02000000, 1.44866:1F1B0000, 1.36674:0E000000, 1.61250:00000000, 1.45378:241B0000, 1.44866:44010000, 16.55847:0D0D0000, [Hostname=BM1PR01MB2595.INDPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please consider adding code. Also, google search `SendAsDeniedException.MapiExceptionSendAsDenied` and you will get a LOT of results that will help you understand what is going on.

Comment: Please check the solution provided in this Stackoverflow [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60406094/transaction-failed-the-server-response-was-5-2-0-storedrv-submission-exception)

Answer (score 0):

The error means the current user cannot send as the user specified in the `From`/`Sender` MIME headers.